# Remove donated troops during preparation phase

Tags: clash-of-clans

Any one know of a way to remove the troops that someone donated during the preparation phase? One of the clanmates donated lvl 3 giants to everyone when lvl 5 wizards were available.

Comment: Thank you for posting this question! It can be a real problem. I'm hoping for resolution to this, but currently I couldn't find a way. I'm worried you might be stuck with them.

Comment: Just wanted to say, an update came out today! You can now dismiss the troops in your Clan Castle on the War screen. There's a little red minus button on the troops now. =)

Answer (score 6):

A recent update added a little red minus button beside the troops in the war screen so you can get rid of them if you don't want them

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to remove the troops, sadly.

However, you are able to change the message on your village requesting specific troops, but of course you aren't guaranteed to get them.

EDIT: Added a comment on the question post

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can always just go to single player and drop those troops off.